# Why do we have to switch off mobile phones during flight in airplanes?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, electronics, electrical-engineering, microwaves

During take offs the flight attendant makes sure that mobile phones are switched off (or maybe turned in airplane mode), why is that necessary?
(I suspect that there is something to do with physics that's why it was posted here.)

Comment: It might have more to do with electrical engineering or electronics.

Comment: One reason why they made that rule was that the phone companies _asked_ them to make it. The physics part of the reason was simple: A plane flying five miles above the average terrain had line-of-sight to hundreds of cell towers back in the when they made the rule--maybe tens of thousands  today. If your phone actually was able to communicate with hundreds of towers, that could confuse and overload their network. I don't know whether a modern cell phone actually can emit a signal that can penetrate the airplane's skin. The technology today is different from back when they made the rule.

Comment: Because 1) a poorly designed mobile might interfere with poorly designed avionics, and 2) the cell networks below you aren’t designed for a bunch of phones with line of sight to lots of towers while moving at 1000 km/hr. Physics per se has nothing to do with it.

Comment: There's an [aviation.se] SE site, where this question has already been asked and answered. There's probably interesting physics issues to be picked up from there, but I'm not particularly convinced that the bare naive question as asked here really is about physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [aviation.se].

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, one reason is that the cell towers couldn't really deal with the signals.

The other, and this is more theoretical in nature, is that the working frequencies of the transmitters in the phone, and the CPU and other chips, might give off signals that interfere with the navigational receivers. This isn't entirely crazy, we had a deskside-PDP-11 machine that you could tell was running from the next room because you could hear it on the radio.

That said, the frequencies in question are very widely separated for exactly that reason, and it seems there are no proven examples of this ever happened in spite of millions of hours of phones being left on by mistake.

Update: if you're curious why even having a *receiver* is an issue, read over the wiki's article on [superheterodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver) and the [ASV radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASV_Mark_III_radar#German%20confusion).

Comment: Now could that be the reason for those "missing" airplanes ?

Comment: No, although some claims to that effect have been made. In every example, this was found to not have actually occurred.

Comment: So, you say they worked that out for the ones not found yet... good going...

Comment: No, I said they found zero examples of interference with instruments, ever. It is difficult to imagine that this problem only occurs on certain flights, and always causes the aircraft to disappear.

Comment: This is why physics is not the venue for this. "There are no proven examples of this ever happened" is largely irrelevant - it's not how aviation works. Safety is paramount, and the bar is "has been proved to be safe", not "has not been proved to be unsafe". (There are no proven examples of an MCAS bringing down a 737 Max 8 - would you feel comfortable flying in one?) Let's not have a discussion about aviation safety with information provided by armchair aviators - there are professionals for this, and this is not their site.

Comment: The chances of a plane going down are one in a million. If there's a one in a million chance of a phone interfering with the avionics then you've halved the safety of the plane by leaving it on. So switch it off.

Comment: PDP-11... that was 40 years ago.  Things have certainly evolved - both in terms of avionics shielding and stray transmissions - since then.